# Coldfusion pack(H* equivalent

Tags: php, coldfusion

I am trying to emulate a php function in coldfusion. The Php output for the following;

```
<?php echo (strtoupper(hash_hmac('SHA256', 'a cow jumps over the moom', pack('H*','specialkey')))); ?>
```

Results in `E9C9E66592306F1BD27A3B1991C7650D4A8920D10E5FFDA955DA692225793F35`

When try in CF

```
<cfset z=hmac("a cow jumps over the moom", "specialkey","HMACSHA256")>
```

Result is `1A905E37DC5F7544E170FB2D47743417AFC7CC0CE53188F30E78BC09D3A61ADF`

It is obviously to do with the `pack(H*` part, as if I run

```
<?php echo (strtoupper(hash_hmac('SHA256', 'a cow jumps over the moom', 'specialkey'))); ?>
```

The result is 
`1A905E37DC5F7544E170FB2D47743417AFC7CC0CE53188F30E78BC09D3A61ADF`

How do I emulate the `pack(H*` in php? I nee to return the result `E9C9E66592306F1BD27A3B1991C7650D4A8920D10E5FFDA955DA692225793F35` in CF?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't share any code.

Comment: You need to tell us the data type of `what` you are trying to pack. The "H*" part is the `how`. To make things clear: `pack(how, what)`

Comment: Sorry, Is this what you mean? <?php echo (strtoupper(hash_hmac('SHA256', 'a cow jumps over the moom', pack('H*','specialkey')))); ?>

Comment: And my CF Code is <cfset z=hmac("a cow jumps over the moom", "specialkey","HMACSHA256")>. It produces 1A905E37DC5F7544E170FB2D47743417AFC7CC0CE53188F30E78BC09D3A61ADF 
If I run the php function without the Pack(H portion I get the same result. I am just pulling my hair out over the pack (H bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it may seem like both sides are using the same key - they are not.

In order to generate the HMAC, both PHP and CF must first decode the value into *binary*, and that value is what is actually used as the "key". The reason you are getting a different result is that the two sides are decoding the key value differently: PHP decodes it from [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) and CF as a plain string using the JVM default ie UTF-8, ASCII, etcetera. As a result, PHP and CF are generating totally different keys and that is why the HMAC codes do not match.

Having said that, I noticed your key value **"specialkey" is not actually a valid hexadecimal string**. So before you spend a lot of time on this, my question would be is the PHP code *really* using arbitrary strings like "specialkey" or is that just for testing purposes? If the real code is using valid hexadecimal strings, then just pass in a *binary* key to CF's HMAC function and the results should be the same:

**ColdFusion:**

```
writeOutput( hmac("a cow jumps over the moom"
            , binaryDecode("7370656369616c6b6579", "hex")
            , "HMACSHA256"));
```

**PHP:**

```
echo (strtoupper(hash_hmac('SHA256', 'a cow jumps over the moom', pack('H*','7370656369616c6b6579'))));
```

**Result:**

```
1A905E37DC5F7544E170FB2D47743417AFC7CC0CE53188F30E78BC09D3A61ADF
```

---

*Update:* If for some reason you really did need to use arbitrary strings as keys, take a look the [Perl docs for pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) (on which the PHP function is based).

Disclaimer: I am not really a PHP guy, so there is a little more to it, but ... essentially `pack(H*)` breaks your key string into pairs of characters and interprets them as hex. The invalid characters like "s", "p", "i", etcetera are converted to null or 0:

```
  sp   --> 00  ("s" and "p" are invalid)
  ec   --> EC  ("e" and "c" are valid hex)
  ia   --> 0A  ("i" is invalid, "a" is valid)
  lk   --> 00  ("l" and "k" are both invalid)
  ey   --> E0  ("e" is valid, "y" is invalid)
```

The resulting binary is this (in hexadecimal):

```
00 EC 0A 00 E0
```

If you decode that hex string back into binary and use it as the key:

```
hmac("a cow jumps over the moom", binaryDecode("00EC0A00E0", "hex"), "HMACSHA256")
```

CF returns the same result as PHP:

```
E9C9E66592306F1BD27A3B1991C7650D4A8920D10E5FFDA955DA692225793F35
```

Comment: Thanks, I had omitted the binaryDecode("00EC0A00E0", "hex"), The special key was just a testing key. Much appreciated